# Let $p$ be a prime number and let $C$ be a cyclic subgroup of order $p$ in $G = S_p$. Compute the order of the normalizer $N_G(C)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Task is:

> Let $p$ be a prime number and let $C$ be a cyclic subgroup of order $p$ in $G = S_p$. Compute the order of
> the normalizer $N_G(C)$.

It's clear that $e$ is in the normalizer, as well at C itself(since it's abelian), so $|N_G(C)| \geq p+1$, but I can't find a way to make any conclusions for the rest of the group.

Comment: How do you get “at least” $p+1$ from the fact that $e$ is in the normalizer? $e$ is in $C$, you already counted it.

Comment: You're correct. It was 5am and i was tired is how i got p+1 :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $C=\langle \alpha \rangle$, then $\alpha=(a_1\, a_2 \ldots a_p)$.  There are $p!$ such expressions, but each cycle can be written $p$ ways as such an expression.  This gives us $(p−1)! $ $ p-$cycles in $S_p$, and we know they are all conjugate.  Each of these cycles generates a group of order $p$, and each such group has $p−1$ generators.  Thus there are $(p−2)!$ cyclic subgroups of order $p$ in $S_p$, all conjugate.  Hence the normalizer of anyone of them has index $(p−2)!$ and hence has order $p(p−1)$.

Comment: Not all $p$-cycles are in $C$. Take $p = 3$ and consider the cycles $(123)$ and $(213)$. $\langle (123) \rangle = \{id, (123), (321)\}$ which does not contain $(213)$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I never claimed that all $p$ cycles are in $C$. I counted the number of $p-$cycles in $S_p$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: Ehr... $(213)=(321)$.

Comment: Wow that was a very silly mistake, my apologies. But @AnuragA, your original post did include the statement "But all $p-$cycles are already in $C$." which I was responding to. Regardless, my example was wrong and your current post is correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop No worries. It's good that we have folks like you who can help disseminate correct information.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding this proof. A lot of the assumptions you make i don't see how you got to them.
Why are there $p!$ such expressions? If we are counting permutations on the set ${a_1 ... a_p}$ then cycles of the form (ab)(c) should be excluded,no? 

Why can cycles of the form $(a_1 ... a_n)$ be written p ways? I assume because $(a,b,c) = (b,c,a)$ ? I don't understand this proof and i dont even know where to begin with understanding it.

Comment: @Hristmar so let me make an attempt to break it down for $p=5$. If we are asked  how many ways to arrange the $5$ symbols in $(1,2,3,4,5)$, then we have $5!$ ways. But we want these to represent a $5-$cycle and we know that a cycle $(12345)=(23451=(34512)=\ldots$, so there are $5$ shifts which will give us the same cycle as $(12345)$, this means even though we had $5!$ permutations but a set of $5$ of them represents the same cycle. So the number of *distinct* cycles will be $5!/5=4!$. Does that help.

Comment: @Hristmar Let me know if you want more explanation for the remainder of the proof.

Comment: @Hristmar the core idea behind the proof is to find those $g\in S_p$ such that $gCg^{-1} \subset C$. But $C$ is cyclic so it is generated by a permutation say $\alpha$. Since $|\alpha|=p$ (a prime), so $\alpha$ must be a $p-$cycle. So our problem now is to find some information about $g\alpha g^{-1}$. But this is a conjugate of $\alpha$, hence has the same cycle structure as $\alpha$, so it must be a $p-$cycle as well. And that's the reason why we are counting how many $p-$cycles are there in $S_p$.

Comment: I understood your explinations in the comments so far. Continuing with the proof, you say that each of these groups has order p, which is true. Afterwards you say there are p-1 generators, which is true since the group is cyclic and we exclude the identity.

However, afterwards you say that there are $(p-2)!$ cyclic subgroups because of this. If there are $(p-1)!$ cycles of order p, then doesnt it follow that each distinct cycle generates a cyclic group of order p? Why $(p-2)!$ ? How does it even connect to the number of generators?

Comment: @Hristmar Ok so we have $(p-1)!$ distinct $p-$cycles in $S_p$. Each such cycle will generate a cyclic subgroup of order $p$. But will each of these cycles generate a distinct subgroup?  NO, because if we take a $p-$cycle say $\beta=(123 \ldots 
 p)$, then all the non-identity elements in $K=\langle \beta \rangle$ are also $p-$cycles and they all will generate this same subgroup $K$. So for each $p-$cycle, there are $p-1$ cycles which will generate the same cyclic subgroup. So how many **distinct** cyclic subgroups of order $p$ can there be? It is $(p-1)!/(p-1)=(p-2)!$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: $(p-2)!$ are the different cyclic subgroups of order $p$ which are conjugated to each other.
Why do the number of conjugated subgroups coincide with the index $[S_p:N_{S_p}(P)]$?
does it have to do with the stabilizing orbit theorem?